# Auto-cropping image with detection of crop-lines

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, android-image

I am working on a project, which is an Android app that uses camera to capture a photo of a ticket and does OCR recognition for only a part of it. I have no previous experience of image processing, but I know it must be some kind of tricky way, because Android applications have small RAM limits.

Below, I attach image before any processing:

[image]

My aim is to automatically detect these lines of (---) and crop it so that the final image look like this one:

[image]

What's more - it's important to stay open-source and do it without sending photos to an external image processing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find the lines. OpenCV has a [implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) that is open source and works on Android.

[HoughLineP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp) is a very efficient Version of the HoughTransform to find Line Segments.

Answer (score 2):

[Olena](http://www-old.lrde.epita.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Olena/) is definitely the way to go!. It's a generic image processing library, but the interesting part is an module that's called Scribo.

[Scribo](http://www-old.lrde.epita.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Olena/Modules#SCRIBO) will do document analysis on the picture to extract text and/or image regions, and optionally send text regions to tesseract for recognition.

Being feasible for Android or not is something that I couldn't tell. I've tried it on OSX and Linux systems and it shows great potential.

Comment: I think the Problem is that it will recognize all the Text and not just the snippet asked for. But you could then surely filter the Text rather than the image which would be a whole lot easier!

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Processing text is a lot easier, but since it's Android application which runs on mobile device I cannot affort to recognize whole image.

Comment: You might want to add this information to your question. As suggested in my answer you could use OpenCV. their implementation of HoughLine detection [HoughLinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp) is pretty efficient. But i have no idea if you save a whole lot of computational load by preprocessing the image like that.